# AM-GM inequality.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image: Graph of function f(x)=[2^(1-x) + 2^(x+1) + 3^x +3^(-x)]/2]

By the AM-GM Inequality, we know that
$$(2^{1-x} + 2^{x+1} + 3^{x} +3^{-x})/4\geq(2^{1-x}\cdot2^{x+1}\cdot3^{x} \cdot3^{-x})^{1/4}$$

By solving this, we get
$$(2^{1-x} + 2^{x+1} + 3^{x} +3^{-x})/4\geq\sqrt{2} \\ \implies f(x)\geq2\sqrt{2}$$

However, if AM-GM is applied separately, we get
$$(2^{1-x} + 2^{x+1})/2\geq[2^{1-x}\cdot2^{x+1}]^{1/2} \\
(2^{1-x} + 2^{x+1})\geq4, \\ ( 3^{x} +3^{-x})/2\geq(3^{x}\cdot3^{-x})^{1/2}\\
3^{x} +3^{-x}\geq2\\
\implies f(x)\geq3$$

Why are the results different?

Comment: Please edit your question. It's impossible to read in this state.

Comment: And also your graph is different from what you wrote. Please clarify.

Comment: The results are different because in the first case there does not exist any value of $x$ such that all the four numbers are equal, so you cannot get the real minimum of the function. Whereas in the second case there exists one value of $x$ such that the two numbers are equal every time you apply the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: The results are different, but not contradictory. For example, both $\sin x \ge -1$ and $\sin x \ge -1001$ hold true for all real $x$, though obviously $-1 \ne -1001$. Maybe you should add some details about what your actual reason was for using AM-GM in the first place.

Comment: A simpler example: $4 = \sqrt{ 4 \cdot 4} \le \frac 12 (4 +4) = 4$ and $4 = \sqrt{2 \cdot 8} \le \frac 12 (2 + 8) = 5$ are both true.

Answer (score 1):

In the first inequality, we have $$\frac{2^{1-x} + 2^{x+1} + 3^{x} +3^{-x}}{4}\geq\sqrt{2}\implies f(x)\geq2\sqrt{2}$$

However, its equivalent condition is:

$2^{1-x} = 2^{x+1} = 3^{x} = 3^{-x}$, which has no solutions, so $f(x)>2\sqrt2$.

(By $3^x=3^{-x}$, we have $x=0$, but $2^{0+1}\neq3^0$)

In the second one, the equivalent condition is:

$2^{1-x} = 2^{x+1}, 3^{x} = 3^{-x}$, which implies $x=0$.

So $f(x)\geq f(0)=3$, then we have the minimum of $f(x)$ is $3$.

In this case, $f(x)\geq f(0)=3>2\sqrt{2}$, so the first inequality still holds.